# Footer last page only html + css

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a page that works fine on screen. When I call ctrl + p everything works fine, but footer repeats on every page. I would like to print my footer  only on the last page.

I already have a .scss to customize some things. My HTML is like this:

```
                    <md-table-container>
        <table md-table>
            <thead md-head>
                <tr md-row>
                    <th md-column><span>{{'relatorioVenda.produtoVariacao'|translate}}</span></th>
                    <th md-column><span>{{'relatorioVenda.qtde'|translate}}</span></th>
                    <th md-column><span>{{'relatorioVenda.valor'|translate}}</span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody md-body ng-repeat="produto in ctrl.resumoPorProduto.produtos track by produto.produtoId">
                <!-- item -->
                <tr md-row class="item">
                    <td md-cell>{{produto.descricao}}</td>
                    <td md-cell>{{produto.quantidade}}</td>
                    <td md-cell>{{produto.totalVenda | currency}}</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- subitem -->
                <tr md-row ng-repeat="variacao in produto.variacoes track by variacao.produtoVariacaoId">
                    <td md-cell class="sub-item"><md-icon md-font-icon="zmdi zmdi-chevron-right"></md-icon> {{::variacao.descricao}}</td>
                    <td md-cell>{{variacao.quantidade}}</td>
                    <td md-cell>{{variacao.totalVenda | currency}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot md-foot>
                <tr md-row class="total">
                    <td md-cell>{{'relatorioVenda.total'|translate}}</td>
                    <td md-cell></td>
                    <td md-cell>{{ctrl.resumoPorProduto.totalVenda | currency}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </md-table-container>
```

And my scss:

```
.total {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

But till now no idea on how to print only on the last page. Any idea?

Best regards.

Comment: There is a [`:first`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-page-3/#valdef-page-first) Page selector, but curiously enough not a matching `:last`. / Can you show more code, especially the CSS? I was under the impression that normally only fixed positioned elements were repeated on every page. Might it perhaps have to do with that you are using a table? Could be the browser thinks that the table footer contains important information concerning the tabular data above (which likely you don’t even have – looks rather like you are using tables for layout purposes), and so repeats it on every printed page.

Comment: CBroe I edited the question and put more code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hello did you thought about media queries? Something like :

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print-style.css" media="print" />`

And then you can maybe set `display: none;` to the footer in first pages.

Comment: I already have something like this. But how can I identify first pages? It´s a html page with ctrl + p, I don't have any idea how many pages this will generate.