# when printing html, place a footer only on the last page of the document

Tags: html, css, pdf, puppeteer

**Edit**

I found a somewhat dirty workaround to my problem. I managed to place a footer at the bottom of my last page by inserting an empty element before it, giving it `page-break-after: always`. Then I gave my footer `margin-top: -130px` (or whatever height the footer has), moving it from the top of the last page to the bottom of the second last page.

There are 2 downsides:

- My generated pdf file has an empty page at the end
- I have to make sure that there is enough space for the footer to appear

Nonetheless this is a working way to place a footer only on the last page when printing html.

**Original Question**

I'm generating pdf files from html with puppeteer.

My documents don't have a fixed length.

I'd like to create a footer that only shows up at the last page.
I'm not using the puppeteer footer utility, because

- I'm already using it for a page number (actually I want 2 footers at the last page and 1 footer at the other pages)
- when using the utility I have to define the size of the footer and I seem unable to define different sizes for different pages.

I imagine that finding some hacky solution with puppeteer is far more difficult than designing an appropriate html document that simply places a div at the end of the last page. If I'm wrong, I happily accept a solution that uses puppeteer utilities.

I tried something similar to these approaches:

[CSS Print page footer only on last page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57241600/css-print-page-footer-only-on-last-page)

[Footer last page only html + css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582287/footer-last-page-only-html-css)

I have a `div class="content"` that contains the entire content. I set its `position: relative` and place a `div class="footer"` with `position: absolute` at the bottom of my content `div`.

I created an example html file that can be found at the bottom of this question.

Puppeteer seems to be using the `@page` directive, by trying to modify my document using it my whole document layout went wrong. Using the directive in my minimal example with some online html2pdf converters didn't help anyways. Although I'd be happy to be proven otherwise, I think that `@page` won't help me. It seems like in the past, there was some `@page :last` directive that could have helped me, but it doesn't exist anymore.

I currently believe that my best approach is to somehow make my content-div cover the last page until the end instead of only wrapping the content. `height: 100vh` or `height: 100%` didn't help. In my example, I gave the content div a border to better understand it's behaviour while testing. When converting to pdf, you can see that the div ends right after the content.

If I manage to cover the entire last page, I can use flexbox to push my footer to the bottom of my page by inserting a growing spacer div.

example.html:

```
<html>

<head>

<style>

    .content {
        position: relative;
        height: 100vh;

        border: 1px solid black;

        font-size: 20px;

        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .content .grow {
        flex-grow: 1;
    }

    .content .footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    /*@page {
        margin: 0;
        size: auto;
    }*/

</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="content">

        <div>
        <p>

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   
        </p>
        <p>

        Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   
        </p>
        <p>
        Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   
        </p>
        <p>
        Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.   
        </p>
        <p>
        Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.   
        </p>
        <p>
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.   
        </p>
        <p>
        Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus.   
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   
        </p>
        <p>
        Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   
        </p>
        <p>
        Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   
        </p>
        <p>
        Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        </p>
        </div>

        <div class="grow">

        </div>

        <div class="footer">

            <p>MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT </p>
            <p>MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT </p>
            <p>MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT </p>
            <p>MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT MY FOOTER CONTENT </p>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```